# How to access response data in microsoft's php graph api

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, guzzle, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using microsoft's graph api to upload files to onedrive. If the upload is successful, I'd like to delete the local file. My code is as follows:

```php
    public function testMoveFile()
    {    
        $graph = new Graph();
        $graph->setAccessToken($acccess_token);

        $response = $graph->createRequest("PUT", "/drives/$drive_id/items/root:/$filename:/content")
            ->attachBody($content)
            ->execute();

        if ($response->getStatusCode() > 201) {
            var_dump($response);
        } else {
            // remove the file
        }
    }
```

The problem is that there doesn't appear to be a getter for the response http status code. When I use `var_dump()` to examine `$response`, I can see that there is a private property called `_httpStatusCode`, but when I try to access it, I get an error because it is private. When I looked through the unit tests, I don't see any checking. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This was easier than I thought. To get the status code, you have to

```
        if ($response->getStatus() > 201) {
```